# Segmentation fault on malloc

Tags: c

After running this function many (not sure exactly how many) times, it seg faults on a simple memory allocation. Why would this suddenly happen? I did notice something strange in GDB. In the function that calls it, normally there's 6-digit long hex value for wrd (wrd = 0x605140 for example), however on the call where it crashes, the hex value is only two digits long. (wrd=0x21). I also checked the wrd->length, and it's 3.

The line that it crashes on is...

```
char *word_temp = malloc(wrd->length * sizeof(char));
```

EDIT:

Here's the code that creates the wrd...

```
while(fgets(input, 100, src) != 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(input[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    struct word *wrd = malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    wrd->letters = input;
    wrd->length = i;
```

If I'm getting an overflow, how do I fix that?

Comment: Most likely `wrd` is not pointing to something valid.

Comment: If you have the option, you should run your application under Valgrind.  It's very likely that you've corrupted the heap by overflowing a dynamically-allocated buffer somewhere.

Comment: Usually, such problems are related to pointer errors (buffer overruns, etc.), possibly somewhere else in the program entirely. Here it might be that you're not accounting for the zero terminator on your strings? Hard to say with so little context.

Comment: `0x21` is almost certainly a bad pointer.  The fact that you can dereference it to find that `3` in GDB is a bit weird, but possible I guess.  You need to figure out where you corrupted `wrd`.  You haven't shown us enough information to help you with that, though.  Editorial aside: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: Corrupted it? How is that possible?

Comment: If `input` is a local array in a function, then as soon as the function terminates you can't use it anymore via `wrd->letters`. If you do use it, you may corrupt memory.

Comment: @SwiftCore.. Have you tried `free`ing the memory inside the `while` loop? For every run of the loop, you are allocating memory, but I am not sure if someone is freeing the same. Can you please try this if you haven't already tried the same?

Comment: You left out error checking for the calls `malloc()` for the sake of readabiltiy, didn't you? In your real code I'm sure you always test the outcome of system calls for error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `wrd->length` does not include the terminating `'\0'`.

Fix 1, allocate `word_temp` like this:

```
char *word_temp = malloc( wrd->length + 1 );
```

Fix 2, include the '\0' by modifying you length count loop:

```
int i = 0;
while(input[i++] != '\0') {}
```

This will increase `i` one more time than code in the question, which is easy to see if you consider case of `input` being empty.

Note that you need to do either fix 1 or fix 2, not both. Choose which ever works with rest of your code.

---

You probably have a second issue with this line:

```
wrd->letters = input;
```

It does not copy input, it copies the pointer. If you change contents of `input`, contents of `wrd->letters` changes too, because they point to same memory location. Also if `input` is a local char array, then once it goes out of scope, `wrd->letters` becomes a dangling pointer, which will be overwritten by other data, and modifying it after that will result in memory corruption.

Possible fix (depending on rest of your code) is to use [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup):

```
wrd->letters = strdup(input);
```

Remember that it is now allocated from heap, so when done, you must remember to do

```
free(wrd->letters);
```

---

About `wrd` being 0x21, that indicates either memory corruption, or that you actually have two separate `wrd` variables, and one one is left uninitialized.

For example, maybe `wrd` is a function parameter `struct word *wrd`, in which case you only modify the local value in function, it does not get passed back to the caller. To modify the pointer of caller, you need to have pointer to pointer: `struct word **wrd` and then do `(*wrd) = malloc...` and `(*wrd)->letters...` etc.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always guaranteed to be `1`. There is no need to write it this way. It's not idiomatic.

Comment: @SwiftCore Added more stuff to the answer. It's quite speculative, and if that does not help, it may still give you some ideas on how to edit your question to be more informative.

Comment: @Wiz Please correct me if I am wrong but I thought that in the case of Unicode characters, sizeof(char) does not come out to be 1.  It is dependent on the language being used.

Comment: @unxnut You are wrong. sizeof char is ALWAYS 1. This has nothing to do with Unicode. (Some encoding schemes, like UTF-8 require multiple bytes to represent a code point, but that has nothing to do with the size of `char`)